# How to add message app icon on home screen in custom launcher programatically?

Tags: android

How i can add application icons on home screen in my custom launcher. In my custom launcher only one button showing which is for open all applications window in grid view. But i want to add more application icons on home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Using above permission You can write below code

```
 Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
 shortcutIntent.setClassName("packageName", "className");
 Intent addIntent = new Intent();
 addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
 addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "shortcut_name");
 addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
 Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.icon));
 addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
 context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```